# How do I distribute ad hoc OTA apps without the .mobileprovision?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, adhoc, ota

I followed a set of instructions from multiple sources about how to deploy apps ad hoc without the need for itunes; however, I ran into a discrepancy. I got the necessary distribution certificate, made an ad hoc provisioning profile, used the profile to build and archive, shared the app, filled out the necessary fields, uploaded the .ipa and .plist files to my server, and tested. I couldn't install the app because there was no provisioning profile on the device. I uploaded the provisioning profile, tried downloading it from the device, and it worked. Now I can download and install the apps without connecting to my computer.

However, when testing on a different device, the app refused to run. I found out that it was because the mobile provisioning file was refusing to install, and that was because developer mode was not turned on on the device. I then found out that in order to turn on developer mode I have to connect to a computer.

Is there a way around this issue, to either turn on developer mode without connecting to a computer, or to not need the provisioning profile installation installed, or to somehow install the provisioning profile on the device without developer mode on?

I don't see a mention of developer mode or the provisioning profile on this page: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html

What am I missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Archive your app with the profile having all the device UDID's that you want to support.  This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

[TestFlightApp.com](http://testflightapp.com)

You can distribute ad hoc (limited to 100 devices) or enterprise (deploying custom apps company-wide > 100 devices).  Plus, Apple just acquired them so either their service will get even better or they'll integrate it with Xcode 6.

Using TestFlight at work and it's amazing! Track who downloads you builds, gather feedback, import the TestFlight SDK and it will even report crashes.